# Brute force chromatic number in Java

Tags: java, colors, matrix, brute-force

This is a brute force attempt at the chromatic number of a matrix. It seems to work in the sense that it gives me the correct number of colors required but instead of 1,2,3,4 it will display 1,2,3,6. For some reason even if the matrix is possibly successful with fewer colors it will still fail and keep going to the max number. Is there a reason why it continues to fail?

"n" is the max number of colors. "v" is the vertex, and "m" is the number of currently used colors.

pseudo code:
http://i42.tinypic.com/deoc2u.jpg

```
static int color(){ 
       int i;
       for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)
       {
               if(color(0,i)){
                       return i;}
       }
       return i;
}

    static boolean color(int v, int m) {

    if(v > n-1)
            return true;
    else
    {
            for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++)
            {
                    boolean match = false;
                    q[v] = i;

                            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                            {
                                    if(input[v][j] == 1)                
                                    {
                                            if(q[v] == j+1)
                                                    match = true;
                                    }
                            }

                    if(match == false)
                    {
                            if(color(v+1,m)) 
                                    return true;
                    }
            }
            q[v] = 0;
            return false;
    }

}
```

sample output:

File Name: file1
Input 
6
0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 1 0 1 
0 1 1 0 1 1 
1 1 0 1 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 0 
1 failed
2 failed
3 failed
4 failed
5 failed

Colors:
1 2 3 1 3 6

Comment: Aren't chromatic numbers a property of graphs? I'm not certain how this relates to matrices... What does your matrix represent? Are the 1's and 0's areas that must be colored in? EDIT: also, is this homework? It's okay if it is, but then it should be tagged as such so people will know to guide you instead of coming up with a full solution.

Comment: The 1's in the matrix represent a link between the 2 vertices of the graph. Every node must be colored, the 1's and 0's just tell you what ones are connected and what ones are not.

Comment: Ah, it's an adjacency matrix. Now we're getting somewhere.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I couldn't think of the correct name for it. Adjacency matrix is indeed what it's supposed to be.

Comment: Well, I think it's still gonna be hard without seeing how your code is being used. That is, the portion calling `color()` and that prints out the result. I'm gonna have to go home now and my college days are becoming a distant memory, but if no-one answers this by tomorrow I'll try to remember taking a closer look.

Comment: Thanks anyways, this is due tomorrow so tomorrow will be just a little to late to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I should be asleep! But I can't count the number of times I've put off an assigment to the absolute last possible moment, so I'm feeling sympathetic regarding your deadline.

It's not really a "brute-force" approach, since that would actually come down to trying each and every possible node coloring combination and check which ones don't conflict. Your approach is a heuristic known as [greedy coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_coloring). It can find optimal results but can also yield an arbitrarily bad solution. That said, I've tried manually going through the sample input you've provided (thank you, Microsoft Paint) and following that algorithm the result should indeed be 4 when starting from vertex 0.

So here's what I believe might be wrong with your code. In the following extract...

```
if(input[v][j] == 1)
{
    if(q[v] == j+1)
    match = true;
}
```

You seem to be comparing the color of the current vertex (which will just be `i` anyway) to a vertex index, rather than the color of that other vertex. I think you'll need to alter the inner test to...

```
if(i == q[j])
```

or, if you wish (won't make a difference)...

```
if(q[i] == q[j])
```

Also, you're doing a bit too many checks. Vertex 0 can be assigned color 1. Vertex 1 then needs to be checked against vertex 0 if it's adjacent. Vertex 2 needs to be checked against 0 and 1 if they're adjacent, and so on. You're checking against vertices that couldn't have been assigned a color yet. So don't limit `j` to `n` but limit it to your current vertex `v`.

Finally, using a construct like `if(match == false)` is rather confusing and not necessary. Just use `if(!match)` instead.

Hope this helps. If you're still stuck and I happen to catch the comments in time, I can provide more pointers.

Comment: That indeed was the simple error in the code. Thanks for the help. Also not so much about last minute, more so this is my 4th project in a weeks time.

Comment: @Brian Didn't mean to imply you've been procrastinating. It's just that I had my share of close deadlines to feel your pain. Mind you, in my case it was most definitely the result of being frighteningly lazy :p Good luck on the assignment. You're close to having it work. I managed to get the algorithm running. And now I really am gonna leave, it's 2:30 AM here.